# If the inequality is true for all pairs of variables, can I substitute in a value?

Tags: inequality

My question links to this problem from the Cambridge STEP exam.
[image]

To deduce $y^2 + 1 \geq 4(y-1)^2$
I simply set $\theta$ to $0$. This meant $y^2 \geq4(y-1)^2$ and adding one to the LHS gets our final inequality. This feels very wrong but I can't tell what I am doing wrong which tells me there is fundamentally something missing in my intuition. I thought because the inequality should hold for any $\theta$ and $y$ that fit the first equality, I can simply replace the value of $\theta$ with any real number.

I compared it to the inequality $(x+y)^2 \geq 4xy$ and found that if I replace x or y with any real number, the inequality always holds true. If what I did in the STEP question is wrong, then why does it work for this inequality?

P.S I feel like it's very obvious what I am doing wrong but I have honestly thought about this for a while now.

P.P.S I think what I am doing is wrong because the actual solution is slightly more complex. I understand the actual solution. The reason I am asking this question is to figure out if what I am doing is incorrect, for future problems. If anyone would like to look at the markscheme for the problem, here is a link: https://www.admissionstesting.org/for-test-takers/step/preparing-for-step/ (This is STEP 2016, paper 2)

Comment: Well, that might work if $\theta=0.$ But the same $y$ can't be true for fixed $x$ and all $\theta,$ so you can't assume $\theta=0.$

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to say that because the inequality must be true for any pair of y and $\theta$, for x to be real, it must also be true when $\theta=0$.

Comment: Have you been given any information about $\theta$, e.g. in the 3 preceding problems?

Comment: Those are seperate problems, not linked to this one. What I have screen shotted is the entirety of the question.

Comment: The problem, as you've shown it, does not define or quantify $\theta$. (It says $x$ is real; why doesn't it say $\theta$ is real?) It is a bad problem.

Comment: You need x being real to be able to solve the first part of the problem. However, $\theta$ and y being real is not relevant. To my knowledge, it does not effect your inequalities or the rest of the problem.

Comment: First part is best solved using determinant of quadratic equation in $x$. For the second part, you are showing that $y^2 + 1 \geq 4 (y-1)^2$ for a specific value of $\theta$ but can you show that is true regardless of the value of $\theta$? The official solution shows that.

Comment: Well, inequalities generally don't even make sense for complex numbers. But the point is that _something_ more should have been said about $\theta$.

Comment: @Math Lover where would you fault this line of reasoning 'inequality must be true for any pair of y and θ, for x to be real, it must also be true when θ=0'. So I set $\theta$ to 0 and reached the final inequality. I think there is a logical fault here, I just can't pinpoint it.

Comment: fault is when you say _inequality must be true for any pair of $y$ and $\theta$_. That is not true. All pairs of $y$ and $\theta$ may not meet the condition $(y \cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2 \ge 4 (y-1)^2$.

Comment: Okay I understand that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the proposed exercise, you can apply the change of variable
\begin{align*}
z = x + \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}
Hence we get that
\begin{align*}
y = \frac{x^{2} + x\sin(\theta) + 1}{x^{2} + x\cos(\theta) + 1} = \frac{z + \sin(\theta)}{z + \cos(\theta)}
\end{align*}

Consequently, on the one hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
y\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) & = \left(\frac{z + \sin(\theta)}{z + \cos(\theta)}\right)\times\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\\\\
& = \frac{z\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) - z\sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{z + \cos(\theta)}\\\\
& = \frac{z(\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta))}{z + \cos(\theta)}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
y - 1 & = \frac{z + \sin(\theta)}{z + \cos(\theta)} - 1 = \frac{\sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta)}{z + \cos(\theta)}
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, one gets that
\begin{align*}
(y\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta))^{2} - 4(y - 1)^{2} = \frac{(z^{2} - 4)(\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta))^{2}}{(z + \cos(\theta))^{2}} \geq 0
\end{align*}

where the last claim results from the AM-GM applied to $z$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I understand, however I was fine with the first part of this question and solved it by creating a quadtratic in terms of x and saying that it's discriminant must be greater than or equal to zero. Its the second part that I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I want to add the solution you gave is very nice so thank you. It's just not the question that I had asked.

Comment: @60q You are welcome! I am going to think about the second part. If I come up with some solution, I will edit my answer in order to include it.

Comment: See that's exactly what I did. It just felt wrong to me, I can't explain it. I still can't properly formulate in my head why that just works. Also the solution did something more complicated than that which made me think doing that is incorrect

Comment: @60q I figured out what we are missing. According to the comment of MathLover, the expression $y$ is in fact a function of $x$ and $\theta$. So when you fix $\theta = 0$, it has only been proved the LHS is greater than or equal to the RHS for a specific value of $\theta$. We have to prove it holds for every possible value of it.